# How to change default location for storing Rundeck Projects

Tags: rundeck, rd

I am using Rundeck Docker Container. It was running well for 2 months and suddenly it crashed. I lost all the data wrt a project that I had created using CLI. Is there a way to change the default path to store all project related data including job definitions, resources etc?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, Rundeck stores the project/jobs data on their [internal H2 database](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#default-database), this database is only for testing purposes and probably will crash with a lot of data (storing projects at filesystem is [deprecated right now](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/configuration.html#storage-types)), the best approach is to use a "real" database like [MySQL](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#using-mysql-as-a-database-backend), [PostgreSQL](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/postgres.html#using-postgres-as-a-database-backend), or [Oracle](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/oracle.html#using-oracle-as-a-database-backend), in that way Rundeck stores all project/jobs data on a robust backend.

Check this [MySQL](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/tree/master/mysql), [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/tree/master/postgres) and [Oracle](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/tree/master/oracle) Docker environment examples.

Of course, having a [backup policy](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#backup-and-recovery) for your instance would be ideal to keep safe all your instance data.